# Where should I create a password salt

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, passwords

I have been searching for a preferred location to create a password salt.

For me it makes sense to create the password salt the database level and do the hashing of the entered password + salt at the database level.

But as I am an ultra-noob on login security, I wanted to know which location is best for creating the salt itself.

From what I have read, I have created a stored procedure that takes a `userlogin` and `password` and compares the stored salt concatenation to validate if the password entered is correct.

What I need to know now, is where should the password salt be created on a new user account?

My intent is to have a non-refundable password if the user forgets. If they forget it gives them a temp and then requires a change afterwards. As well, if the password changes, I also want to change the salt accordingly.

I have no illusion of total security, only want to mitigate the opportunity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The place to generate the salt and to hash the password, should be in the code, not in the database.

To hash passwords you need a slow key-derivation function like BCrypt or PBKDF2, but most databases have no implementations of such functions. These functions have a cost factor, which controls the necessary time to calculate the hash-value (the longer the more secure against brute-forcing). The salt as well as the cost factor is usually stored in the same string as the password-hash, so you need only a single field to store the hash.

To verify the password, you first have to search with the username for the password-hash, then the function can extract the used salt and the cost factor, and finally the entered password can be hashed with the same parameters for comparison.

There is another reason to do it in the code, password-systems have to switch to stronger algorithms or have to increase the cost factor in future, then it is much easier to handle backwards compatibility in code, as with SQL statements.

Comment: got any good reads on this implementation pattern? Have this implemented at the code level http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: The linked article is exactly what you need, it shows code for using the PBKDF2 algorithm, the salt will be generated automatically, and is included in the resulting hash-value. For more general informations you may have a look at my [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php) too.

Comment: Looked over that solution and some others.  Is there a way to have a keymaster (code) and a gatemaster (db) structure?  That way you have to have to both parts in order for it to work effectively?  Most solutions rely solely on the source-code to handle all the aggregations instead of put part on source and rest on database (mssql)

Comment: Not sure i understood you correctly. If you store the hash-values with the salt in the database, and used a server-side key to encrypt the hash-values, then an attacker already needs both, access to the database as well as access to the code. Encrypting the hash-values is probably the best way to add a pepper to the hashes.

Comment: I haven't got the code anymore but I solved this once with bcrypt as assemblies in sql server 2008 R2 where {username,password,costfactor} was sent to a clr stored procedure for user creation or password reset. I stored salt+hash as one varchar in the user table. Does this qualify as generating the salt and hash in the code or in the database?

Comment: @DavidSöderlund - How did you solve the problem of the verification? Could you make sure, that a query did not check every stored hash, to find a match of user and password?

Comment: @martinstoeckli - I made a stored procedure that took name and password and queried the user table with name in the where clause and the matching function in the select clause. Thus it validates the name first and if no user with that name exists the set it empty, if it's not empty and the value is 0 then the password is incorrect and if the value is 1 then the password for that username is correct. Whereclause gets checked first so it only runs the function 0 or 1 times. As fun as this subject is I recreated my entire sollution for a blogpost I'm making but it's in swedish. :P

Comment: @DavidSöderlund that was going to be my approach.  Send the web-site hashed form (salted) as the `@pwd` and then have the database "pepper" added to that to form the full Hash and if it is correct then `1` else `0`.  I am simply using this schema to follow the SSL form, public key + private key = access.  Without both, you cannot have access to the system.  Still working out the technical design but needed some advise from those that have done it before.

Comment: @martinstoeckli the thought is that the Web-server is alot easier to hack than a database server, albeit neither are ultimately that hard.  but if i allow the web-server to hash and then hand off then let the mssql database have its own key to hash from, then i will have mitigated and added an addition level of processing.  I am not trying to Encrypt an Encrypt, more Adding a PepperHash to a SaltedHash.

Comment: @GoldBishop so that would mean that only app1 can validate users created by app1 unless app2 knows the salt+hashing algorithm used by app1? Thats a great idea actually if you are only running one application. Avoiding sniffing up the password as it is sent to the database from the application could otherwise be solved by using HTTPS I think? That way you could have more than one application that don't need to know about each other.

I've never used my solution further than proof of concept for creating and validating users and password.

Comment: @GoldBishop - David Söderlund's solution is neat and will work fine, from perspective of security it doesn't matter whether the hash function will run in the application or in the database though. What matters is, where the keys are stored. The first thing an attacker needs, is the hashed password so he needs read access on the db, that is usually the easiest part. Then if you add a server-side secret (pepper), the attacker needs privileges on the server with the code as well. What you probably have in mind is, that the db-server adds a secret too, so he needs privileges on the db-server too.

Comment: Yeah the actual comparison is being executed inside a Function, so its done behind the curtain and only thing that is responded with is a bit value saying Yeah or Nay.  The one thing I have learned is that you never return a response of the final hash, only the partial hash from the web-server.